# I got a warning and couldn't use FontAwesome in React Native on Expo

Tags: react-native, font-awesome, expo

Now I am trying to use FontAwesome in React Native App on Expo.

I followed the flow about how to use custom font through Expo on Expo document but these icons couldn't work and I couldn't see any fonts.

Fortunately I don't have any error but warning.

This is my code below.
Please teach me.

Thank you.

```
import { Font } from 'expo';

import { fontAwesome } from '../../assets/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf';


class Help extends React.Component {
 state = {
  fontLoaded: false,
 };

 async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
   FontAwesome: fontAwesome,
 });

 this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
 }

 renderHelpLists() {
  return HelpLists.map((value, index) => {
   return (
     <TouchableOpacity
      key={index}
      style={styles.helpListsBox}
     >
      <Text style={styles.helpListText}>
        {value.name}
      </Text>
      {
        this.state.fontLoaded ? (
          <Text style={styles.rightIcon}>
            {'\f054'}
          </Text>
        ) : null
      }
     </TouchableOpacity>
   );
  });
 }


 const styles=Stylesheet.create({
  rightIcon: {
   fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
  },
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not yet familiar with using Font Awesome by importing TTF files in React Native.

However, could you try using the Font Awesome React Native component?

See https://github.com/fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FonteAwesome'.

However I am not sure how to use Expo-Icons.